Add numbered/alphabetic labels beneath plots using ggarrange
I am trying to make a multiplot using ggarrange, with numbered/alphabetic labels below each plot. The example code below gives the correct labels, but they are incorrectly placed next to the plot titles, not beneath the x axis labels as i would like. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the correct placement. Have anyone encountered a similar problem, and did you get around it?
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
gg1 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=hp,y=mpg))+
 

 geom_point(aes(color=factor(cyl)),alpha=.5)+
  stat_smooth(method='lm', se=F, color='red')+
  ggtitle('plot 1')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1,
        legend.position = c(1, 1), 
        legend.justification = c(1,1), 
        legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA))


gg2 <- ggplot(mtcars)+
  geom_density(aes(x=hp, color=factor(cyl)))+
  ggtitle('plot 2')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1,
        legend.position = c(1, 1), 
        legend.justification = c(1,1), 
        legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA))


gg3 <- ggplot(mtcars)+
  geom_density(aes(x=mpg, color=factor(cyl)))+
  ggtitle('plot 3')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1,
        legend.position = c(1, 1), 
        legend.justification = c(1,1), 
        legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA))


gg4 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=hp,y=mpg))+
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(cyl)),alpha=.5)+
  stat_smooth(method='lm', se=F, color='red')+
  ggtitle('plot 4')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1,
        legend.position = c(1, 1), 
        legend.justification = c(1,1), 
        legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA))



ggarrange(gg1,gg2,gg3,gg4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, labels = paste0("(",letters[1:4],")"))


Code shamelessly adapted from a related question, giving the following output:


Can't test from here, but does adding the label.y = 0 argument to the ggarrange call help?

@PGSA just tested, it works, please post as an answer. The value might depend on the output device, for me label.y = 0.2 worked well.

Grea, this works! However, I need it directly underneath the x axis lable of each plot. Here label.y = 0 gives about the correct vertical positioning, but using the label.x argument (0.25 should give the correct horizontal positioning) doesn't work, as it gets printed behind the plot below (or placed out of bounds for the bottom row). Any suggestions for how to solve it?

You can alter the y position of the labels using the label.y argument to ggarrange.
Some experimentation may be required to find the right offset for your output device and settings.
